# On Forming a Question - It is time to feed the horses

Tags: questions

Here is the sentence.
Leena said to her brother, "It is time to feed the horses."

which question below is grammatically correct?

1. What time is it time to do?
2. According to Leena, what time is it for?

Any other possible answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What is it time to do?

or

What is it time for?

“According to Leena” can be added to either of these, at either the beginning or the end.

Answer (score -1):

"It is time to feed the horses" has a context in the present moment and no later than an immediate future. It could also be rhetorical without any sense of an urgency to do anything other than gauging her brother's response.

Comment: thanks James. I found this on one of the lessons that I had to teach. The question formed to ask my Korean students was "What time is it time to do?" Being a non native speaker, I could not pinpoint the error in the question. Still, it sounded not right. How does one put it in rhetoric form?